# How to change the tick labels on an axis

Tags: r, ggplot2, label, axis-labels, geom-bar

I have tried to put as much information here as possible. I hope my question makes sense. This is my first time using stack overflow. I am making plots of behavioural data. I have measures the activity of animals over time whilst being exposed to varying stimuli. The stimuli range between no stimuli (REST in this example), a vibration (VIBRATION in this example) and a light flash (PULSE in this example). I am trying to replicate some figures that I have made in excel. The excel figure looks like this:

[image: Figure from excel]

I am using a MacOS version 11.2.1

packages I am using include:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(tidyr)
library(tibble)
library(ggplot2)
library(ggpubr) 
library(dplyr) 
library(plyr)
```

I have summarised my raw data using this code:

```
  mydata <- ddply(df, c("BLOCK", "SEQ_BIN", "CONDITION"), summarise,
                   N    = length(distance),
                   mean = mean(distance),
                   sd   = sd(distance),
                   se   = sd / sqrt(N))
```

This gives me the correct data set which looks like this:

```
  BLOCK SEQ_BIN CONDITION  N      mean       sd        se
1     1       1     PULSE 48 3.3416667 2.364258 0.3412513
2     1       2      REST 48 0.7354167 1.408257 0.2032644
3     1       3      REST 48 1.0250000 1.483885 0.2141804
4     1       4      REST 48 0.8708333 1.377935 0.1988878
5     1       5      REST 48 0.7604167 1.379136 0.1990612
6     1       6      REST 48 1.1270833 1.271578 0.1835365
```

I have also included the full dataset here:

```html
structure(list(BLOCK = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), SEQ_BIN = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 
9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 
25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 1, 2, 3, 
4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 
21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 
37, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 
18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 
34, 35, 36, 37), CONDITION = c("PULSE", "REST", "REST", "REST", 
"REST", "REST", "VIBRATE", "VIBRATE", "VIBRATE", "VIBRATE", "VIBRATE", 
"VIBRATE", "VIBRATE", "VIBRATE", "VIBRATE", "VIBRATE", "VIBRATE", 
"VIBRATE", "VIBRATE", "VIBRATE", "VIBRATE", "VIBRATE", "VIBRATE", 
"VIBRATE", "VIBRATE", "VIBRATE", "PULSE", "VIBRATE", "VIBRATE", 
"VIBRATE", "VIBRATE", "VIBRATE", "REST", "REST", "REST", "REST", 
"REST", "PULSE", "REST", "REST", "REST", "REST", "REST", "VIBRATE", 
"VIBRATE", "VIBRATE", "VIBRATE", "VIBRATE", "VIBRATE", "VIBRATE", 
"VIBRATE", "VIBRATE", "VIBRATE", "VIBRATE", "VIBRATE", "VIBRATE", 
"VIBRATE", "VIBRATE", "VIBRATE", "VIBRATE", "VIBRATE", "VIBRATE", 
"VIBRATE", "PULSE", "VIBRATE", "VIBRATE", "VIBRATE", "VIBRATE", 
"VIBRATE", "REST", "REST", "REST", "REST", "REST", "PULSE", "REST", 
"REST", "REST", "REST", "REST", "VIBRATE", "VIBRATE", "VIBRATE", 
"VIBRATE", "VIBRATE", "VIBRATE", "VIBRATE", "VIBRATE", "VIBRATE", 
"VIBRATE", "VIBRATE", "VIBRATE", "VIBRATE", "VIBRATE", "VIBRATE", 
"VIBRATE", "VIBRATE", "VIBRATE", "VIBRATE", "VIBRATE", "PULSE", 
"VIBRATE", "VIBRATE", "VIBRATE", "VIBRATE", "VIBRATE", "REST", 
"REST", "REST", "REST", "REST"), N = c(48L, 48L, 48L, 48L, 48L, 
48L, 48L, 48L, 48L, 48L, 48L, 48L, 48L, 48L, 48L, 48L, 48L, 48L, 
48L, 48L, 48L, 48L, 48L, 48L, 48L, 48L, 48L, 48L, 48L, 48L, 48L, 
48L, 48L, 48L, 48L, 48L, 48L, 48L, 48L, 48L, 48L, 48L, 48L, 48L, 
48L, 48L, 48L, 48L, 48L, 48L, 48L, 48L, 48L, 48L, 48L, 48L, 48L, 
48L, 48L, 48L, 48L, 48L, 48L, 48L, 48L, 48L, 48L, 48L, 48L, 48L, 
48L, 48L, 48L, 48L, 48L, 48L, 48L, 48L, 48L, 48L, 48L, 48L, 48L, 
48L, 48L, 48L, 48L, 48L, 48L, 48L, 48L, 48L, 48L, 48L, 48L, 48L, 
48L, 48L, 48L, 48L, 48L, 48L, 48L, 48L, 48L, 48L, 48L, 48L, 48L, 
48L, 48L), mean = c(3.34166666666667, 0.735416666666667, 1.025, 
0.870833333333333, 0.760416666666667, 1.12708333333333, 2.32291666666667, 
1.16875, 0.758333333333333, 0.625, 0.633333333333333, 0.35, 0.36875, 
0.35, 0.277083333333333, 0.227083333333333, 0.21875, 0.56875, 
0.495833333333333, 0.533333333333333, 0.335416666666667, 0.445833333333333, 
0.34375, 0.0291666666666667, 0.129166666666667, 0.0354166666666667, 
1.00625, 0.0291666666666667, 0.2125, 0.225, 0.139583333333333, 
0.283333333333333, 0.139583333333333, 0.235416666666667, 0.35, 
0.2375, 0.225, 3.32083333333333, 0.554166666666667, 0.75625, 
0.69375, 0.395833333333333, 0.404166666666667, 3.46041666666667, 
1.325, 0.53125, 0.441666666666667, 0.270833333333333, 0.204166666666667, 
0.210416666666667, 0.164583333333333, 0.158333333333333, 0.0708333333333333, 
0.139583333333333, 0.0708333333333333, 0.252083333333333, 0.122916666666667, 
0.225, 0.341666666666667, 0.108333333333333, 0.258333333333333, 
0.35625, 0.25625, 0.98125, 0.108333333333333, 0.09375, 0.0645833333333333, 
0.0395833333333333, 0.1, 0.0354166666666667, 0.11875, 0.2125, 
0.139583333333333, 0, 2.24375, 0.54375, 0.654166666666667, 0.45, 
0.725, 0.435416666666667, 2.23333333333333, 0.764583333333333, 
0.49375, 0.345833333333333, 0.139583333333333, 0.329166666666667, 
0.16875, 0.122916666666667, 0.104166666666667, 0.164583333333333, 
0.0291666666666667, 0.0354166666666667, 0.40625, 0.145833333333333, 
0.15, 0.075, 0.075, 0.0979166666666667, 0, 0.135416666666667, 
0.66875, 0.0291666666666667, 0.0291666666666667, 0.0645833333333333, 
0.0583333333333333, 0, 0.0291666666666667, 0, 0.0875, 0.0645833333333333, 
0.164583333333333), sd = c(2.36425808913848, 1.4082567438992, 
1.48388506752276, 1.3779352937489, 1.37913626736869, 1.27157794137556, 
2.55769507135119, 2.2472826380585, 1.28341852899488, 1.37724671378744, 
1.31283894644042, 1.10299399122609, 0.829035905081857, 1.07624247841294, 
1.34484667849256, 0.64436661407411, 0.928429525046852, 2.49494435617822, 
2.02809609211823, 2.23895238927013, 1.8469629566184, 3.0888239401645, 
2.18455957389925, 0.202072594216369, 0.529535458131408, 0.245373864405591, 
1.26531574564225, 0.202072594216369, 0.668636274879778, 1.00095698889464, 
0.587000881993369, 0.991095103179357, 0.599197897666018, 0.747332727554306, 
1.30171735991589, 0.69851666545251, 0.616613952126812, 2.5305754398432, 
1.41029019698653, 1.47704510223708, 1.47394480828569, 0.902704761549878, 
1.03922195391723, 2.7874139302299, 2.05193214603088, 1.04640341474165, 
1.0162160377897, 0.691885592969579, 0.555421378595944, 0.669785479577217, 
0.584367118409322, 0.568998124116615, 0.34329959208988, 0.787060132697794, 
0.34329959208988, 0.930565964445507, 0.413721863263043, 0.723319769784915, 
1.43064236923575, 0.580474249738892, 0.73276896400566, 2.23110565568028, 
1.08704288509817, 1.4658751289305, 0.580474249738892, 0.368669978695702, 
0.314534159653053, 0.274241377865072, 0.526732198095615, 0.245373864405591, 
0.648617597073994, 0.831718293143139, 0.739677785897586, 0, 2.25160994411233, 
1.15591103427078, 1.4281305043968, 0.999148573706846, 1.60352006402935, 
1.07079004107095, 2.91279885387243, 1.62970948766472, 1.28798147370051, 
1.21549540435749, 0.599197897666018, 0.917433592781036, 0.504092295669346, 
0.521960128636781, 0.41869012221417, 0.581081011429535, 0.202072594216369, 
0.245373864405591, 1.41397376514228, 0.589250636025739, 0.661719230811325, 
0.364078551262446, 0.519615242270663, 0.387841590460307, 0, 0.938194187433142, 
0.86814947482464, 0.202072594216369, 0.202072594216369, 0.314534159653053, 
0.282717311132842, 0, 0.202072594216369, 0, 0.342472238353057, 
0.314534159653053, 0.602650028405864), se = c(0.341251261049463, 
0.203264352544578, 0.214180360795183, 0.198887828192953, 0.199061173803622, 
0.183536466687192, 0.369171484487398, 0.324367309007061, 0.185245508299537, 
0.198788440236426, 0.1894919797825, 0.15920346943723, 0.119661025741719, 
0.155342221156255, 0.194111897961614, 0.0930063095231238, 0.134007259052349, 
0.360114198913158, 0.292730456181722, 0.323164941161967, 0.266586140046725, 
0.445833333333333, 0.315314014512877, 0.0291666666666667, 0.076431859824405, 
0.0354166666666667, 0.182632596589107, 0.0291666666666667, 0.0965093333229472, 
0.144475696746389, 0.0847262793083548, 0.14305225615328, 0.0864867668788333, 
0.107868187856924, 0.187886717039061, 0.100822196208112, 0.0890005578116235, 
0.365257102849531, 0.203557856216416, 0.213193096845449, 0.212745607958599, 
0.130294209269895, 0.14999876871047, 0.402328545740287, 0.296170894217444, 
0.151035323295508, 0.146678150743174, 0.0998650833373525, 0.0801681706115103, 
0.0966752067333022, 0.0843461282797969, 0.08212780503178, 0.0495510279764452, 
0.113602344870374, 0.0495510279764452, 0.134315627517829, 0.0597156072811378, 
0.104402215948875, 0.206495439248086, 0.0837842410860988, 0.105766089655618, 
0.322032362724376, 0.156901125583024, 0.211580850071601, 0.0837842410860988, 
0.0532129278605243, 0.0453990954362558, 0.0395833333333333, 0.0760272440903367, 
0.0354166666666667, 0.0936198860679497, 0.120048195109032, 0.106763292200389, 
0, 0.324991901835823, 0.166841386698873, 0.206132882787852, 0.14421467449752, 
0.231448185154577, 0.154555229614472, 0.420426300594621, 0.235228302851028, 
0.18590411263806, 0.175441649726138, 0.0864867668788333, 0.132420132938934, 
0.0727594556502784, 0.0753384551936743, 0.060432713691847, 0.0838718195924555, 
0.0291666666666667, 0.0354166666666667, 0.204089533482991, 0.0850510033324046, 
0.0955109440092177, 0.0525502123943856, 0.075, 0.0559801116637976, 
0, 0.135416666666667, 0.12530658324671, 0.0291666666666667, 0.0291666666666667, 
0.0453990954362558, 0.0408067289217784, 0, 0.0291666666666667, 
0, 0.0494316097507778, 0.0453990954362558, 0.0869850390318153
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -111L))
```

I then try to make my figure. I like that R easily lets me break up the large figure from excel into blocks using facet_wrap. However, if I use "CONDITION" for the x axis I get the correct labels but it is summarised and I do not want this. See code and figure below:

```
ggplot(mydata, aes(x = CONDITION, y = mean)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity") +
  facet_wrap(~BLOCK, ncol = 1) +
  ggtitle("habituation (vibration)") +
  theme(legend.position = "none", plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5)) +
  labs(x = "condition", y = "distance")
```

right labels wrong data
[image: right labels wrong data]

If I instead use the time bin data (SEQ_BIN in this example). I get the correct data the same as the figure in excel but it is numbered rather than having the labels of what stimuli the animals are receiving at the time. See code and figure below:

```
ggplot(mydata, aes(x = SEQ_BIN, y = mean)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity") +
  facet_wrap(~BLOCK, ncol = 1) +
  ggtitle("habituation (vibration)") +
  theme(legend.position = "none", plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5)) +
  labs(x = "condition", y = "distance")
```

[image]

Is there an easy way that I can change the tick labels in that last figure in ggplot to use the labels from "CONDITION" but over time?

Comment: Welcome to SO. "I have tried to put as much information here as possible. I hope my question makes sense."  It kind of makes sense. If you could share the data with us in the following way, this would help us help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the advice. I have added the dataset using the dput() function as suggested in this link. I am hoping I have uploaded this into the query correctly. I have also included all of the packages that I am using plus my OS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do it would be to use `geom_text` to label along the x axis for each bar's condition. You might have to play around with the spacing between plots (and between axis labels and plots) to get it to fit well and show all text clearly:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- tibble(
  BLOCK = rep(1:3, each = 20),
  SEQ_BIN = rep(1:20, times = 3),
  CONDITION = case_when(
    SEQ_BIN == 1 ~ "PULSE",
    SEQ_BIN == 17 ~ "VIBRATE",
    TRUE ~ "REST"
  ),
  mean = rnorm(60, 5, 2)
)

df %>% 
  ggplot(aes(SEQ_BIN, mean)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  facet_wrap(~ BLOCK, ncol = 1) +
  ggtitle("habituation (vibration)") +
  theme(legend.position = "none", plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5),
        # These lines replace x axis ticks with labels and space things out
        axis.text.x = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.x = element_blank(),
        panel.spacing = unit(2, "cm"),
        axis.title.x = element_text(margin = margin(2, unit = "cm"))) +
  labs(x = "condition", y = "distance") +
  geom_text(aes(y = -1, label = CONDITION), angle = 90, hjust = 1) +
  # This ensures it doesn't cut the text off or expand the lower axis to include text
  coord_cartesian(clip = "off", ylim = c(0, NA))
```

[image]

(All done on synthetic data in an attempt to mirror your own)

<sup>Created on 2021-03-15 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>

Comment: YES! This worked perfectly!! Thank you so much. You are right that I just need to play a bit with the spacing but at least its there.

Comment: @Shanelle You should click on the check mark of this answer because it helped you solve the problem. It will give both of you some reputation points and mark this question as answered.

Comment: Can't seem to mark this as closed. Something about rep points? I tried marking as answered too but I don't think it worked?

Comment: @Shanelle You should see a Grey check mark (✔️) near the top of the answer. It turns green when you click on it. That means you accepted the answer as solution.

Comment: @Shanelle Closing a question means something different: it means the question is off-topic and should not be answered. You should not close your question.

Comment: @Shanelle Maybe this page will help: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: Sorry should have said mark answered rather than closed. Pointers above should help!

Comment: Uh huh! I have now marked as accepted. Thank you so much everyone for the kind/patient help and support.